# how to enter the data inside any loop in python

Tags: python, loops

I have the following data:

```
x = 2
y = 5
z = 9
a = array
```

The numbers in the array are `[1,2,3,4,5]`.
I do not know how to use loops and I also do not know how to include the variables inside the loop.

This is my try using the for loop:

```
x * y * z * a = B
For (x = 2, y = 5, z = 9, a = array, a++)
print (B)
```

What I am trying to do is get the program to print values in a table of `a` and `B`. And the calculation I am trying to attempt is something like this; for example for the first number from the array: `2 * 5 * 9 * 1 = 90`, then second number from the array: `2 * 5 * 9 * 2 = 180` and so on. I don't even know how to get the math functions into the python program. I shouldn't have to type the list in that array. That array is already printed.

Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: Step one would be learning *any Python at all*. `a = array` is not how you create a list (or even an array, for that matter) and is likely a `NameError`. I don't know what you think you're doing with that `For(...)`, but it's certainly not a Python `for` loop. You can't just guess.

Comment: [Read the tutorial.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Comment: Your code is missing fundamental structure that is necessary if you are going to understand for loops. I recommend this tutorial in order learn what you need. It does cover for loops. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> y = 5
>>> z = 9
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in a:
...     output = x * y * z * i
...     print x, '*', y, '*', z, '*', i, '=', output
...     
... 
2 * 5 * 9 * 1 = 90
2 * 5 * 9 * 2 = 180
2 * 5 * 9 * 3 = 270
2 * 5 * 9 * 4 = 360
2 * 5 * 9 * 5 = 450
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [119]: x = 2

In [120]: y = 5

In [121]: z = 9

In [122]: array = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [123]: answer = []

In [124]: for iteration in array:
   .....:     answer.append(x*y*z*iteration)
   .....:     

In [125]: answer
Out[125]: [90, 180, 270, 360, 450]
```

Of course, you could do this a lot simpler, by computing `x*y*z` beforehand:

```
mult = x*y*z
answer = []
for iteration in array:
    answer.append(mult*iteration)
```

... and you could also use a list comprehension, if you wanted to:

```
answer = [mult*iteration for iteration in array]
```

... and if you didn't want to create the array:

```
answer = [mult*iteration for iteration in range(1,6)]  # range(1,6) gives you a sequence of 1,2,3,4,5
```